# The stochastic differential of $\cos (B_t^{(1)}B_t^{(2)})$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Let ($B_1$, $B_2$) be a bi-dimensional correlated Brownian motions Calculate the stochastic differential equation of the process $\cos(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})$.

**Attempt:**

Let $X_t$ be the stochastic process defined by $X_t = \cos(B_{1,t}B_{2,t})$.

Call $Y_t:= (B_{1,t}B_{2,t})$, so the process becomes  $X_t := \cos(Y_t)$

We calculate the stochastic differential of $X_t$: $$dX_t = - \sin (Y_t)dY_t - \frac{1}{2} \cos (Y_t) d\langle Y_t \rangle$$

The stochastic differential for $Y_t$ is: $dY_t = B_{1,t} \space dB_{2,t} + B_{1,t} \space dB_{1,t} + t \space dt$

I don't get out of this exercise at all. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Please take a look at [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6717/bizarre-ways-of-using-tex). Make sure you place your dollar signs `$...$` around each line of TeX. Otherwise, it will render incorrectly and make it difficult to read.

Comment: Now, it should be fine. Thanks Jose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you apply the multidimensional version of Itô's formula directly. Set $f(x,y) = \cos (xy)$, so that the derivatives of interest are:
$$\begin{align*}
f_x(x,y) &= -y\sin (xy) \\
f_{xx}(x,y) &= - y^2 \cos(xy) \\
f_y(x,y) &= -x \sin (xy) \\
f_{yy}(x,y) &= -x^2 \cos (xy) \\
f_{xy}(x,y) &= -xy \cos(xy)
\end{align*}$$
Itô's formula then gives us for $Z_t = \cos (B_t^{(1)} B_t^{(2)})$ that:
$$
\begin{align*}
dZ_t &= f_x(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)})dB_t^{(1)} + f_y(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)})dB_t^{(2)} + \frac{1}{2}\left( f_{xx}(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)}) + f_{yy}(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)}) \right)dt + f_{xy}(B_t^{(1)}, B_t^{(2)})d\langle 
 B^{(1)}, B^{(2)}\rangle 
\end{align*}$$

where I have substituted $dt = d\langle B^{(1)}\rangle_t = d\langle B^{(2)} \rangle_t$. You may also substitute $d\langle 
 B^{(1)}, B^{(2)}\rangle = \rho dt$, where $\rho \in [-1,1]$ is the correlation coefficient.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @GloBag578 The comma was a typo. Itô's formula gives terms $\frac{1}{2} f_{xx}(B_t^1, B_t^2) d\langle B^1 \rangle_t$ and $\frac{1}{2} f_{yy}(B_t^1, B_t^2) d\langle B^2 \rangle_t$. Since we have $d\langle B^1 \rangle_t = d\langle B^2 \rangle_t = dt$, you can "factorise" out this common $dt$ differential, as I did in my solution above.

Comment: For the typo OK. Tomorrow, I post my final solution. Very Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thank you for support!

Comment: Hi Hose, I have another question. It' correct this partial derivates?  $f_{xy} = -xy \; sin(xy)$ . Thank you!!

Comment: @GloBag578 It should be cos, not sin. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok sorry, it's $f_{xy} = -xy \; cos (xy)$. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jose, it's correct? $$dX_t= - B_{2,t} \space sen (B_{1,t} B_{2,t}) \space dB_{1,t} \space - B_{1,t} \space sen (B_{1,t} B_{2,t}) \space dB_{2,t} + \frac{1}{2} [(- B_{2,t}^2 \space cos (B_{1,t} B_{2,t}) -  \space \\ \hspace{5cm} - B_{1,t}^2 \space cos (B_{1,t} B_{2,t}) \space - 2 \space B_{1,t}B_{2,t} sen(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}) \space \rho \space ] \space \space dt $$